# Plural or singular meaning of the word "Filter" in a phrase "Filter updates"

Tags: meaning, nouns, grammatical-number

I would like to know if the phrase: 
"Filter updates" means "updates of filters" or "updates of 1 filter". 
So can this phrase "Filter updates" be used in plural meaning, so to say? Instead of saying "updates of filters".

Answer (score 3):

The term *filter* in the phrase *filter updates* is known as an **adjectival noun** or **attributive noun**.  These are ordinary common nouns that are used as adjectives.

In general, attributive nouns are singular. In your example, *filter updates* means *updates relating to or on filters*. The term *updates* is plural in the example given, so it suggests there is more than one update, either multiples for a single filter or one or more updates to more than one filter.

Whether the updates affect a single filter or multiple filters, the term *filter* would remain singular, since it is used as an adjective and adjectives do not usually change form regardless of the number of the nouns they modify. In English (unlike many highly declined languages), we say *large boats* not *larges boats*.

Comment: Could it not be (to) filter updates?

Comment: @Pureferret It is possible for the phrase *filter updates* to mean *filter [verb] updates [direct object]*. However, the context of the question seems to clearly indicate an adjectival, not verbal, usage for *filter*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it seems perfectly acceptable.

Change it with any other noun and it should still work. e.g.

> Breakfast updates

Could mean *updates of breakfasts* or *updates of one breakfast*.

Comment: Why I picked "breakfast" I do not know. Must be hungry. :)

Comment: I was thinking of _car repairs_, maybe that is less meal-time dependant and I believe it is also a commonly used phrase :)

Comment: "Filter updates" automatically made me think of software updates, and separating them with filters. :)

Comment: Have you heard of books shops?

Comment: Thank you, Ronan :) One more thing. Can you please explain me why is it so? Is there any rule that proves that both variants (sing. and pl.) of perception are possible in this case?

Comment: No, but I have heard of drinks bars. Hmmm...

Answer (score 0):

"Filter Updates" might also mean that you are to scan through all updates, and discard some and keep others.  In this case Filter is a verb.

Comment: It could mean that, but the question indicates that this is not the sense.